# What's going on with this Backbone/node/express 400 Bad Request error when deploying to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, backbone.js, xmlhttprequest, express

I'm getting a `400 Bad Request` error when deploying my Backbone.js/node.js app to Heroku.

From the logs:

```
Error: Bad Request
    at Object.error (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/utils.js:42:13)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/json.js:57:73)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:64:17)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnMessageComplete [as onMessageComplete] (http.js:130:23)
    at Socket.ondata (http.js:1506:22)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:374:27)
```

From the network tab of Chrome devtools:

[image]

The error does not appear when running on `localhost`.

[image]

Interestingly, a direct get to the URL works fine. A manual `jQuery.ajax()` call also works fine. This `Backbone.sync` call is the only instance that the resource fails, but it fails consistently.

What's going on with this Backbone/node/express 400 Bad Request error when deploying to Heroku? My guess would be something related to a proxy/router artifact such as `x-forwarded-for` but at this point I can't tell if the error is at the Backbone, express or Heroku level.

Backbone request headers (400 Bad Request)

```
GET /services HTTP/1.1
Host: karmr.herokuapp.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1082.0 Safari/536.5
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Referer: http://karmr.herokuapp.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/plain
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Length: 420
Connection: keep-alive
```

Direct `GET` (200 OK):

```
GET /services HTTP/1.1
Host: karmr.herokuapp.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1082.0 Safari/536.5
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Length: 84
Connection: keep-alive
```

Here are the header diffs ([bigger version here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61jsU.jpg)):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know if you have tried this yet, but when sending a response from your server instead of using the plain old

`response.send(response to send);`

try using

```
response.json(response to send);
```

instead.

I had this same error showing up and for the life of me could not find the solution, after switching it worked instantly. Hope this helps.

Comment: this turned out to be sort of a fix -- apparently a bug in the express body parsing middleware. removing the middleware invocation fixed it, but so would this i believe.

Comment: Did this do the trick? I came across the same problem (in spine.js - which is built on top of backbone), and my searches so far have pointed me to the following cause: since backbone.sync sets `Content-Type: application/json` request header, the server (or body parser, maybe?) expects the `body` of the request to be not-empty. No solution yet though, I don't feel like disabling the `bodyParser` for one method!

**Edit:** I just confirmed that BodyParser causes this to be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you two lines of investigation:

1. **The Url is not responding JSON**: Check what this URL is responding and why it is not responding a proper JSON. If you see the headers the *client* is expecting `application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01` and the URL is responding `text/plain`.
2. **There is a CROSS-Domain issue**: Check all the [issues about CROSS-Domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cross-domain)